# Fail to compile c++ source to swc using Alchemy on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: c++, macos, flash, swc, alchemy

When I tried to compile a [.cpp] file to [.swc] file, I got this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.3.dylib
```

And I found that my libltdl is

```
Poechant:src poechant$ ls -l /usr/lib/libltdl.*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     15 10 11 08:17 /usr/lib/libltdl.7.2.2.dylib -> libltdl.7.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  88848 10 11 08:17 /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     15 10 11 08:17 /usr/lib/libltdl.dylib -> libltdl.7.dylib
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the post here
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3892045:

The following set of commands would work( i tested, too )

```
cd /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s libltdl.7.dylib libltdl.3.dylib
```